# How to change Windows computer's desktop background?

Tags: python, windows, background

I am trying to make a python file that changes your background on a Windows computer.
This is my code:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "BG.png" , 0)
```

All it is doing now is changing the background to pure black.

Comment: Try passing the full path the the file. Ex: `r"C:\users\you\pictures\BG.png"` or whatever.

Comment: I am trying to make it so any user who runs it gets their background changed.
and BG.png is in the same folder as the py file

Comment: I don't think that matters. Windows needs to find the file, not Python.

Comment: So How would I find the username of the person who ran it then?

Comment: I also defined where it was for my pc and it did not change it

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue because your code works fine for me when using the full path.

Comment: maybe idk (running this on virtual machine)

Answer (score 0):

Either the file you stated "BG.pmg" is wrong hence "BG.png" or the background image you chose is a panoramic file which is not supported as a background

Comment: I changed the typo from pmg to png still not working